# How to create a syntax according to the boolean value of an object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a text according to the value of an object.

The object is `filterAttributes`.

The thing is to connect text with **and** when one or more value of the object is **true**.

The thing is the key word `and`. From my second example `overwrites` and `recurring` is true. I am add `and` text at the end of overwrites I think it is not the way to write this syntax.

```
let filterAttributes = {
        priority: false, // priority = :priority
        overwrites: true, //overwrites = :overwrites
        recurring: true, //recurring = :recurring
        search: false, //contains(filterText, :keyword)
    };
```

**Desire text if all attributes are true**

```
let text = 'priority = :priority and overwrites = :overwrites and recurring = :recurring and contains(filterText, :keyword)'
```

**Desire text for current case**

```
text = `${filterAttributes.overwrites && 'overwrites = :overwrites and'} ${filterAttributes.recurring && 'recurring = :recurring'}`
```

**(FALSE) Desire text for current case if recurring become false**

```
text = `${filterAttributes.overwrites && 'overwrites = :overwrites and'}`
```

Can someone help me solve this prob. I am stuck at this step for a very long time and i can't think of a good solution

Comment: Take a look at [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). Functions [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) might help, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array, then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it in the end:

```
const filterAttributes = {
    priority: false, // priority = :priority
    overwrites: true, //overwrites = :overwrites
    recurring: true, //recurring = :recurring
    search: false, //contains(filterText, :keyword)
};

const parts = [];
if (filterAttributes.priority)   parts.push('priority = :priority');
if (filterAttributes.overwrites) parts.push('overwrites = :overwrites');
if (filterAttributes.recurring)  parts.push('recurring = :recurring');
if (filterAttributes.search)     parts.push('contains(filterText, :keyword)');
const text = parts.length
  ? parts.join(' and ')
  : 'true'; // you probably don't want the empty string
```

If there's a lot of different names that all share the same simple syntax, you can handle them with a helper function or loop as well:

```
for (const attr of ['priority', 'overwrites', 'recurring', …]) {
  if (filterAttributes[attr]) {
    parts.push(`${attr} = :${attr}`);
  }
}
if (filterAttributes.search) parts.push('contains(filterText, :keyword)');
```

Since this looks like it's building an SQL string, I recommend this (with explicit whitelisting of attributes) over a dynamic solution that uses `Object.keys(filterAttributes)`.